# How to use icons from a Nuget package in WPF/XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

Just starting with WPF/XAML.  Have a small app in Visual Studio 2015 Professional.  Need to add a few icon buttons to the app. Installed a `NuGet` package called `MaterialIcons`.  The only *documentation* on how to use the package is this example

```
<mi:MaterialIcon Icon="ic_search"/>
```

However, when I add that to my XAML code, I get the following compiler errors:

```
The namespace prefix "mi" is not defined.

MaterialIcon is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.

The type 'mi:MaterialIcon' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

My XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
                        Click="OnSettingsMenuItemClick">
                    <mi:MaterialIcon Icon="ic_search"/></Button>
```

When I remove `<mi:MaterialIcon Icon="ic_search"/>` from the code, the app compiles fine.

I see `MaterialIcons` entry among the project `references`.  I don't know how to fix the `namespace` issue.

Comment: There should also be a XAML namespace declaration in the example, like `xmlns:mi=...`. You'll need that too, and you can of course change the name `mi` to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:mi="clr-namespace:MaterialIcons;assembly=MaterialIcons"
```

You can either add it to a parent element:

```
<Window ... xmlns:mi="clr-namespace:MaterialIcons;assembly=MaterialIcons" ... >
```

Or directly to the `Button` element:

```
<Button xmlns:mi="clr-namespace:MaterialIcons;assembly=MaterialIcons"
        x:Name="button" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
        Click="OnSettingsMenuItemClick">
    <mi:MaterialIcon Icon="ic_search"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: This works perfectly and fixes the errors in Visual Studio.  The icons even show up nicely in the VS designer window.  However, when I run the app from VS, I get an outline for the button, but no icon in it.  Do you happen to know how to fix that?

Comment: You should see the icon. Try to remove everything else.

Comment: You are right. It was a mismatch between the size of the button and the size of the icon image.  Thanks!